# Reshape a dataframe with a list column

Tags: r

Having a dataframe such as the following and using the unested option to receive new columns for the column files:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <-  structure(list(url = "https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702", 
                       files = "list(sha = c(\"bca42f706ba9ef5b822cfc8581ca79bec93f28c2\", \"9f29ababe866e9d6df73bb730a0eb5d216562838\", \"3c3fe578da77c9d2dc92e339ecd4d954ed24ba15\", \"03f52efb0d0be91e580dd1d636b5fcc54033aacc\", \"6fd0a99f12295e0ce9ea56062ced4a92a7152470\", \"abfeef07a423b9fcae17e4a08de9a93f39448c25\", \"abfeef07a423b9fcae17e4a08de9a93f39448c25\", \"f98b02b85225bdf54206e1955aaa34ebe298899e\", \"d97d3cf93f85d48dd09dba15f7b0f652429980c3\"), filename = c(\"src/manifest.json\", \"src/skin/.DS_Store\", \"src/skin/dashboard.html\", \"src/skin/dist/main.dev.js\", \"src/skin/dist/welcome.dev.js\", \"src/skin/images/icon.png\", \"src/skin/images/icon2.png\", \"src/skin/main.js\", \"src/skin/welcome.html\"), status = c(\"modified\", \"modified\", \"modified\", \"removed\", \"removed\", \"modified\", \"removed\", \"modified\", \"modified\"), additions = c(8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4), deletions = c(8, 0, 1, 203, 142, 0, 0, 3, 3), changes = c(16, 0, 1, 203, 142, 0, 0, 3, 7))"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
                       
df_reshaped <- df %>%
  rename_all(funs(str_c("Files.", .))))) %>%
  unnest(files)
```

How is it possible to receive the following result:

```
df2 <- data.frame(url = c("https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702", "https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702", "https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702", "https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702", "https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702", "https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702","https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702", "https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702","https://api.github.com/repos/aleecia/CCPABrowserTool/commits/fc795a994d6284633393ca940796ce82fd69f702"),
           Files.sha = c("bca42f706ba9ef5b822cfc8581ca79bec93f28c2", "9f29ababe866e9d6df73bb730a0eb5d216562838", "3c3fe578da77c9d2dc92e339ecd4d954ed24ba15", "03f52efb0d0be91e580dd1d636b5fcc54033aacc", "6fd0a99f12295e0ce9ea56062ced4a92a7152470", "abfeef07a423b9fcae17e4a08de9a93f39448c25", "abfeef07a423b9fcae17e4a08de9a93f39448c25", "f98b02b85225bdf54206e1955aaa34ebe298899e", "d97d3cf93f85d48dd09dba15f7b0f652429980c3"),
           Files.filename = c("src/manifest.json", "src/skin/.DS_Store", "src/skin/dashboard.html", "src/skin/dist/main.dev.js", "src/skin/dist/welcome.dev.js", "src/skin/images/icon.png", "src/skin/images/icon2.png", "src/skin/main.js", "src/skin/welcome.html"),
           Files.status = c("modified", "modified", "modified", "removed", "removed", "modified", "removed", "modified", "modified"),
           Files.additions = c(8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4),
           Files.deletions = c(8, 0, 1, 203, 142, 0, 0, 3, 3),
           Files.changes = c(16, 0, 1, 203, 142, 0, 0, 3, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may evaluate the text in `files` column as code, get the data in separate columns (`unnest_wider`) and then bring it in separate rows (`unnest_longer`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  # Add rowwise if you have more than one row in the data.
  # rowwise() %>%
  mutate(files = list(eval(parse(text = files)))) %>%
  unnest_wider(files) %>%
  unnest_longer(sha:changes) %>%
  rename_with(~paste0("File.", .), -url)

# A tibble: 9 × 7
#   url                               File.sha File.filename File.status File.additions File.deletions File.changes
#  <chr>                             <chr>    <chr>         <chr>                <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… bca42f7… src/manifest… modified                 8              8           16
#2 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… 9f29aba… src/skin/.DS… modified                 0              0            0
#3 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… 3c3fe57… src/skin/das… modified                 0              1            1
#4 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… 03f52ef… src/skin/dis… removed                  0            203          203
#5 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… 6fd0a99… src/skin/dis… removed                  0            142          142
#6 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… abfeef0… src/skin/ima… modified                 0              0            0
#7 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… abfeef0… src/skin/ima… removed                  0              0            0
#8 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… f98b02b… src/skin/mai… modified                 0              3            3
#9 https://api.github.com/repos/ale… d97d3cf… src/skin/wel… modified                 4              3            7
```